# How to assign one coloumn values to other dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the 2 tables called 'follow' and login .it contains the following   fields.

```
Table Name: follow
Fields:     id,user_id,follow_id

Table Name: login
Fields:     id,email,username,password,phone
```

I want to display the person name  in the 'login' table.
I have to give their user_id dynamically to fetch the follow_id in the table and also assign the above follow_id as user_id then fetch the follow_id to display the name from login table.

i have written the query like below and it returns empty set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT follow.follow_id,follow.user_id,login.username 
FROM follow,login 
WHERE  follow.user_id =".$userid." 
    AND follow.user_id=follow.follow.id 
    AND login.id = follow.follow_id
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an un-necessary condition  `and follow.user_id=follow.follow.id`

What you mean by 'also assign the above follow_id as user_id'.